# sung case with where

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with 2 columns, each having a set of ID's. I want to add a third column to the table, that says "true" if a number in column 1 is present in column 2 as well. 
If not then the third column should say "false"

I am trying to use the following code

```
case when 
where Id (SELECT P_id FROM Tree)
then True 
else false 
end 
as Type
```

but the case and the where are not working together. 
Can some one help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM   tree t2 
                      WHERE  t1.id = t2.P_id) THEN 'true' 
         ELSE 'false' 
       END AS Type 
FROM   tree t1
```

Another way using `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN t2.p_id IS NOT NULL THEN 'true' 
         ELSE 'false' 
       END 
FROM   tree t1 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT p_id 
                  FROM   tree) t2 
              ON t1.id = t2.p_id
```